# Setting Invocable Variable value for a Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, variable

I'm having difficulty finding a way to write the syntax to set my invocable variables in the test class:
Here's the code.

```
global class EmailPreventivoAccettato {
global class Parametri {
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public string IDPreventivo;
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public string Gruppo;
}
```

this class is called by a method that send an e-mail:

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Invia preventivo in allegato (.csv)')
public static void SpedisciMail(Parametri[] inputs) {
```

I wrote the test class:

```
EmailPreventivoAccettato.Parametri[] Parametri = new EmailPreventivoAccettato.Parametri[]{};
Parametri[0].IDPreventivo = '0Q03E000000I5OLSA0';
Parametri[0].Gruppo = 'TEST';
EmailPreventivoAccettato.SpedisciMail(Parametri);
```

but It return me an error when I run the test:

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

someone can help me?...

Comment: You List is empty and youre attempting to get [0] element of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with invocable variable.

You are trying to access the 0 index element immediately after creating instance `Parametri` in test class. You should add element in list instead. Try below:

```
EmailPreventivoAccettato.Parametri Parametri1 = new EmailPreventivoAccettato.Parametri();
Parametri1.IDPreventivo = '0Q03E000000I5OLSA0';
Parametri1.Gruppo = 'TEST';

EmailPreventivoAccettato.Parametri[] Parametri = new EmailPreventivoAccettato.Parametri[]{};
Parametri.add(Parametri1);
EmailPreventivoAccettato.SpedisciMail(Parametri);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created the list, but not an Object in it, change your code a bit:

```
EmailPreventivoAccettato.Parametri ParametriObj = new EmailPreventivoAccettato.Parametri();
ParametriObj.IDPreventivo = '0Q03E000000I5OLSA0';
ParametriObj.Gruppo = 'TEST';
EmailPreventivoAccettato.SpedisciMail(new List<EmailPreventivoAccettato.Parametri>{ParametriObj});
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply! I solved the problem :)